# Match Evaluator not working

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I got this code from a site. It converts unicode to Hindi font. It uses match but I am not following how to define it elsewhere. It generates error near '>'.

```
string input = "0928;0940;0932;092E;";
Regex rx = new Regex(@"([0-9A-Fa-f]{4});");
string output = rx.Replace(input, match =>  ((char)Int32.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString());
textBox1.Text = output;
```

**Updated**

Error: 'match' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: The error is: match does not exist in current context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're truly using C# 2.0 (based on your tag), lambda expressions are not supported until C# 3.0.  As such, you can't use `match => ...`.

Try this instead for your `string output =  ...` line:

```
    string output = rx.Replace(input, delegate(Match match) {
        return ((char)Int32.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString();
    });
```